# Terminal emulator with no header bar

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, gnome-terminal, virtual-terminal

I'm looking for a terminal emulator that lets me get the most out of my vertical space by getting rid of the header bar.  I work in a GNOME environment and am mostly happy with gnome-terminal, but this is something I wish I had.  It's nice if it has tabs in the Google Chrome-style, but in its minimal mode it should look something like:

[image: Mock-up]

I.e., there's a close button and a small space to grab to move the window.

Preferrably it's VTE-based and lightweight.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hooray, I got the "Tumbleweed award" for this Q!

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the following terminals:

- tilda
- guake
- yakuake
- stjerm

Second two are drop-down terminals so they don't take out much of screen real-estate.

Tilda isn't actually drop-down, but a very minimalistic terminal, without any window embellishments  at all. It can be moved around the screen by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, double clicking on it, and dragging around

[image]

Exiting can be done with `exit` command

Comment: Thanks! But all these are "drop-down", Quake-style terminals, right? I want something that stays put.

Comment: @skagedal added edit, please refer. What you really want is tilda

Comment: @skagedal if you like the answer, don't forget to upvote; this solves your question, click grey check-mark to accept the answer

Comment: Thanks! I've tried Tilda for a day now, and while it's neat it's not quite what I want. I want something that's  closer to a "regular" terminal like `gnome-terminal`, but with a slim interface. In particular, I really want regular resizing handles at the edges.